# Using system icons on Galaxy Watch

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

If Samsung / Tizen has an intention to put applications into their Store which is suited to System UI, can I expect to have system icons as resource?

I'd like to use this "gear" system icon in my list:

[image]

And I know this is a generic and "easy-to-find-on-Google" icon, but still, I need other icons too and it's very tiring all the time hunting down information from Tizen.

So the question is straightforward: (where) are the icons used on Samsung Watches located

- on device?
- online?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it's allowed to get images installed in the product binary;;

Images in the emulator can gets like below way

sdb root on

sdb pull ./usr/apps/org.tizen.watch-setting/res/images/b_setting_list_call.png